# How to redirect my-doamin.tdl/someurl to an index file in a different folder than webroot with nginx?

Tags: nginx

I've installd rocketchat on ubunru with nginx and like to redirect

https://chat.myserver.tdl/privacy-policy to /a/folder/outside/webroot/index.html

which redirection rule to apply in this usecase?

Comment: Is there just one file in `/a/folder/outside/webroot` or are there css/js files for `index.html` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you need to serve that `index.html` when you visit `/privacy-policy`? If so, use the [alias](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive:

```
location = /privacy-policy {
    alias /a/folder/outside/webroot/index.html;
}
```

By the way, if you really need a redirect:

```
location = /privacy-policy {
    return 301 /a/folder/outside/webroot/index.html;
}
```